# python tkinter grid method doesn't change position of label

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my label/text to be a desired location but when i use the method grid(row=, column=), my text will always appear to be top left which is by default. What is the problem with my code?Here is my code:

````
class ticTacToeUI():
    master = 0
    player1 = 0
    player2 = 0


    def __init__(self):
        self.setUp()
        self.playerDisplay()
        #self.boardDisplay()
        #self.quitButton()
        self.runUI()

      
    def setUp(self):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.title("Tic Tac Toe Game")
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.master.configure(background="white")
        self.master.resizable(1,1)


    def playerDisplay(self):
        text = tk.Label(self.master, text="Player 1: O\nPlayer 2: X",bg="white",fg="black", font=(None,15))
        text.grid(row=400, column=500)```
````

Comment: empty rows and empty columns have a size of zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because it only has one widget, try adding more widgets
or
text.place(x=400, y=500)